# How to put my emailpass[0] and emailpass[1] on request.get url?

Tags: python

I'm making a python `get.requests` to my website API, and I'm using `python.split` as the delimiter on the data1| data2, as the and the problem is, the data that gonna sent to website is on the URL, how do I put the split on the URL? like split[0] and split[1]
, here the code

```
import requests
tanya = str(raw_input("[+] Enter Mailist File: "))
mailist = open(tanya, 'r').read().split('|')
# mailist[0] as email
# mailist[1] as password
getlogin = requests.get('localhost/check.php?ajax=1&do=check&mailpass=email|password&delim=|&email=0&bank=0&card=0&info=0')
responsetexted = getlogin.text
print responsetexted
```

Trace back when im putting normal text on mailpass instead on mail[0] and mail[1]

```
{"error":2,"msg":"<b><font color=red>False Credentials<\/font><\/b> => username@mail.com|hello123"}
```

Comment: what do you get when you run it ? do you have any error message from server ?

Comment: @furas its error when i run it, not from the server, the script

Comment: you can use dictionary with parameters  `requests.get('localhost/check.php', params={'ajax': 1, 'do': 'check', 'mailpass': 'email|password'}` and it should convert correctly encode your parameters: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls And you can use `emailpass[0]` and `emailpass[1]` in this dictionary.

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback). I see some mistake in code and it has nothing to do with params and '|' - and I expect see this in your full Traceback).

Comment: and add Traceback in question, not in comment.

Comment: @furas how do i put like 'mailpas': mail[0] | mail[1] ?

Comment: @furas have add the traceback , that without the parameters u giving me

Comment: you have strings so `mail[0] + "|" + mail[1]` or `"{}|{}".format(mail[0], mail[1])` In Python 3.6+ `f"{mail[0]}|{mail[1]}"`

Comment: if it is your server then you should create log files on server with more explanation.